# Sort only Certain Column Names based on Month and Year

Tags: pandas, date, sorting

I have more than 100 of columns and organize as below:

```
import pandas as pd 

data = [[11, 1, 6, 8, 45, 67, '30-06-2021', 43578, 3.4, '30-04-2022', 6.7, 5000, 6744, 8.9, 8978, '31-03-2022', '31-01-2022', 
         '28-02-2022', 5.6]]
dat = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['a', 'b', 't', 'u', 'g', 'd', 'Start', 'Apr-22Total', 'Mar-22Rate', 'Apr-22', 'Feb-22Rate', 'Feb-22Total', 'Jan-22Total', 
         'Apr-22Rate', 'Mar-22Total', 'Mar-22', 'Jan-22', 'Feb-22', 'Jan-22Rate'])

    a   b   t   u   g   d    Start   Apr-22Total Mar-22Rate Apr-22  Feb-22Rate  Feb-22Total Jan-22Total Apr-22Rate  Mar-22Total  Mar-22       Jan-22     Feb-22  Jan-22Rate
0   11  1   6   8   45  67  30-06-2021  43578     3.4     30-04-2022   6.7         5000    6744      8.9            8978    31-03-2022  31-01-2022  28-02-2022  5.6
```

How can I organize the order of column names that contain month and year only according to the month and year order?

My expectation is as follow:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
cols = dat.filter(regex='(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-\d\d').columns
sorted_cols = cols[pd.Series(cols).str.split('-', expand=True).set_axis(['0','1'],axis=1).pipe(lambda x: x.assign(**{'0':pd.to_datetime(x['0'], format='%b').dt.month})).sort_values(['0', '1']).index]
dat = dat[dat.drop(cols, axis=1).columns.tolist() + sorted_cols.tolist()]
```

Output:

```
>>> dat
    a  b  t  u   g   d       Start      Jan-22  Jan-22Rate  Jan-22Total      Feb-22  Feb-22Rate  Feb-22Total      Mar-22  Mar-22Rate  Mar-22Total      Apr-22  Apr-22Rate  Apr-22Total
0  11  1  6  8  45  67  30-06-2021  31-01-2022         5.6         6744  28-02-2022         6.7         5000  31-03-2022         3.4         8978  30-04-2022         8.9        43578
```

Comment: it's say that `df` and `sorted_cols` are not defined?

Comment: Oops, sorry! A few typos on my part :) Check now.

Comment: yeah, works well. thanks so much